# In React Navgiation 3, how to push a screen from a different stack and pop back to the calling screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation 3. I have the following routers:

```
const StackA = createStackNavigator(
 {
   MainA: MainA,
   AddA: AddA,
 },
 {
   initialRouteName: 'MainA'
 }
); 

const StackB = createStackNavigator(
 {
   MainB: MainB,
   DetailsB: DetailsB,
 },
 {
   initialRouteName: 'MainB'
 }
); 

const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
     A: StackA,
     B: StackB
  }
)
```

I am in screen `DetailsB` and I want to push a `AddA` screen.  According to docs, I can navigate to `StackA` and push the `AddA` screen using the NavigationActions and StackActions like so:

```
        const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'StackA',
        params: {},
        action: StackActions.push({
            routeName: 'AddA',
            params: {
                someParam: someData,
            }
        })
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
```

The `AddA`screen has a Cancel button and I want to pop the screen and go back to the `DetailsB` screen.  If I use a `StackActions.pop()` in `AddA`, it pops back to the `MainA` screen instead.

Any guidance on how to implement this?

Comment: Is there an issue with directly using the `AddA` screen in `StackB`? Like so: `{ MainB: MainB, DetailsB: DetailsB, AddB: AddA },`

Comment: Honestly, I had not thought about that approach.  Let me try it out.

Comment: Work wells.  It was too obvious of a solution. When one stands to close to the forest, one can only see one tree...  Thanks.